# REGEX of hive output is different from spark sql regex output

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, hive

I researched many of the similiar question but how to correct it to fit in spark sql statement when executing is not mentioned clearly.

```
test1= spark.sql("""SELECT regexp_extract(UPPER("This is the first sentence.This is second sentence. This is the third sentence"),'\\.([^\.]+)\\.',1) as s""")
test1=test1.toPandas()
test1
```

[image]

But in Hive I wrote

```
SELECT regexp_extract(UPPER("This is the first sentence.This is second sentence. This is the third sentence"),'\\.([^\.]+)\\.',1)
```

the out put is different

[image]

[image]

Above are the versions I am using.
I would like the same output as hive in spark sql how do I achieve getting second sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

test1 = spark.sql("""
    SELECT regexp_extract(
        UPPER("This is the first sentence.This is second sentence. This is the third sentence"),
        '\\\\.([^\\.]+)\\\\.',
        1
    ) AS s
""")
test1 = test1.withColumn('s', expr("trim(trailing '.' from s)"))
test1 = test1.toPandas()
test1
```